# How to write .set() for this error? To update m2m field?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I'm trying to edit the M2m field. Gives an error: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use analog.set() instead. How to solve this problem (I don’t understand where to put set())

```
def editpart(request, id, **kwargs):

    added = ''
    error = ''
    PartAllView = Part.objects.order_by('-id')
    part = Part.objects.get(id=id)
    form = PartForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        part.brand = request.POST.get("brand")
        part.number = request.POST.get("number")
        part.name = request.POST.get("name")
        part.description = request.POST.get("description")
        part.images = request.FILES.get("images")
        part.images0 = request.FILES.get("images0")
        part.images1 = request.FILES.get("images1")
        part.images2 = request.FILES.get("images2")
        part.analog = request.POST.get("analog")
        part.save()
        added = 'Запчасть успешно отредактирована'

    form = PartForm()

    data = {
        'added': added,
        'error': error,
        'form': form,
        'PartAllView': PartAllView,
        'part': part,
    }

    context_object_name = "part"

    return render(request, 'kross/editpart.html', data)
```

UPD
`Part model`

```
class Part(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True, max_length=5000)
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
    images = models.FileField('Главное изображение', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images0 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images1 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images2 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
...
```

Comment: We would need your `Part` model to answer your question. But it seems that your `analog` field is a many to many field. You cannot set this field directly. You should read the [ManyToMany relationship documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) to find out how to use those fields.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou I update question